# Remove certain points from findContours to get better result from fitEllipse

Tags: python, opencv, curve-fitting, contour, ellipse

I want to fit an ellipse to a partly damaged object in a picture. (The pictures here are only simplified examples for illustration!)

Image with damaged elliptical object

[image]

By doing this

```
def sort(n):
    return n.size

Image = cv2.imread('acA2500/1.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

#otsu binarization
_, binary = cv2.threshold(Image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#invert binary image for opencv findContours
inverse_binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

#find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(inverse_binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

#sort contours by length
largest_contours = sorted(contours, key=sort, reverse=True)

#fit ellipse
contour = largest_contours[0]
ellipse = cv2.fitEllipseDirect(contour)
```

I get this result, which is not very satisfying.

[Result of cv2.findContours and cv2.fitEllipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZzVA.jpg)

So, I've built this loop to get rid of the contour points which are not on the ellipse.

```
contour = largest_contours[0]
newcontour = np.zeros([1, 1, 2])
newcontour = newcontour.astype(int)
for coordinate in contour:
    if coordinate[0][0] < 600:
        newcontour = np.insert(newcontour, 0, coordinate, 0)
newellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(newcontour)
```

And get this result, which is good.

[Result after trimming the contour points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q2qV.jpg)

The Problem is, that I have to do a lot of these fits in a short time period. So far this does not reach the desired speed.

Is there any better/faster/nicer way to trim the contour points? Since I don't have a lot of coding experience, I would be happy to find some help here :-)

**Edit:**

I edited the example pictures so that it is now clear that unfortunatly a `cv2.minEnclosingCircle` approach does not work.

Also the pictures now demonstrate why I sort the contours. In my real code I fit an ellipse to the three longest contours an than see which one I want to use trough a different routine.

If I don't trimm the contour and pick the contour for `cv2.fitEllipse` by hand, the code needs around `0.5s`. With contour trimming and three times `cv2.fitEllipse` it takes around `2s`. It may only take `1s`

Comment: Don't `sorted` to get the largest contour, use `max`: `max(contours, key=size)`. Don't create an empty numpy array and insert into it, use a list comprehension or filter and then cast it: `newcontour = np.array([co for co in contour if co[0][0] < 600])` or `np.array(filter(lambda co: co[0][0] < 600, contour))`

Comment: And also: tell us what is the current speed performance and what would you like to have.

Comment: @Alexander Reynolds
`newcontour = np.array([co for co in contour if co[0][0] < 600])` works perfect. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

If the object is an circle, then you can use `cv2.minEnclosingCircle` on the contour to capture it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2019/02/13 08:50 (CST)
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54661012/3547485

import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')

## Convert to grayscale and threshed it
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU|cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

## Find the max outers contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

## Use minEnclosingCircle
(cx,cy),r = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnts[0])
cv2.circle(img, (int(cx), int(cy)), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

## This it
cv2.imwrite("dst.jpg", img)
```

Here is my result.

[image]